# Adding a file to GNU dependency list?

Tags: c++, c, sed, makefile

I made a simple makefile to compile AVR code. I have a rule as follows:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
    $(CC) -M $(FLAGS) $*.c > $*.d | sed -e ':?:? avr.rules ?'
```

I'm trying to make it so that in say test.d, it will say

```
test.o: test.c test.h avr.rules
```

I've done it before with a similar sed command but can't seem to get it now. Can someone give me a pointer here?

Answer (score 1):

You could just say

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
    $(CC) -M $(FLAGS) $*.c > $*.d
    echo '$@: avr.rules' >> $*.d
```

There's no problem with having multiple dependency-tracking targets (since none of them have a recipe).

If you insist on doing it with sed,

```
    $(CC) -M $(FLAGS) $*.c | sed 's/:/: avr.rules/' > $*.d
```

will also work.

Side note: You could use `$<` instead of `$*.c`.

Comment: Ah ok I placed the sed in the wrong spot. On another note, the reason why I want avr.rules to be included, is because depending on an input flag, $(FLAGS) changes value, so I want it to rebuild the object with the new flag. However it doesn't seem to be doing so